# How to separate a string with 2 uppercases and a space with regex in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe, regex-lookarounds

I have a dataframe column, teams, where I am trying to split the team name, 'CubsWhite Sox', into two parts, 'Cubs' and 'White Sox'.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data = [{'teams':'CubsWhite Sox','area':'Chicago','league': 'MLB'}, {'teams': 'Red Sox','area':'Boston', 'league': 'MLB'}, {'teams': 'Blue Jay','area':'Toronto', 'league': 'MLB'}] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

so far I could only achieve this result.

```
df["team"] = df.apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[A-Z][^A-Z]*(?:\s[A-Z][^A-Z]*)", x["teams"]), axis=1)
df
    teams           area    league   team
0   CubsWhite Sox   Chicago MLB      [White Sox]
1   Red Sox         Boston  MLB      [Red Sox]
2   Blue Jay        Toronto MLB      [Blue Jay]
```

Also after white, red and blue there are two spaces as I have discovered from here.

```
df["team"] = df.apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[A-Z0-9][^A-Z]*", x["teams"]), axis=1)
df
    teams           area    league  team
0   CubsWhite Sox   Chicago MLB     [Cubs, White , Sox]
1   Red Sox         Boston  MLB     [Red , Sox]
2   Blue Jay        Toronto MLB     [Blue , Jay]
```

which I can easily remove with

```
df['teams'] = df['teams'].str.replace(r' +', '')
```

Can you help me to split these team names like this, please using re.findall?

```
df
    teams           area    league  team
0   CubsWhite Sox   Chicago MLB     [Cubs, White Sox]
1   Red Sox         Boston  MLB     [Red Sox]
2   Blue Jay        Toronto MLB     [Blue Jay]
```

thank you!

Comment: You do not need `re.findall`, there is `Series.str.findall` in Pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['team'] = df['teams'].str.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)?')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zDHgiu/2). *Details*:

- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase letter followed with any zero or more lowercase  letters
- `(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase letter followed with any zero or more lowercase letters.

Pandas test:

```py
>>> df['teams'].str.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)?')
0    [Cubs, White Sox]
1            [Red Sox]
2           [Blue Jay]
Name: teams, dtype: object
```

Comment: I have replaced \WA-Z by a-z  (it did not make a difference) for easier understanding.

Comment: @bluetail That is fine. In Python, I just like the `[^\W\d_]` construct to match any letters and all similar negated character classes where substraction is emulated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df['new_teams'] = (df.teams.str.extract('([A-Z][a-z]+)?([A-Z]\w+\s+\w+)')
                     .apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna()), axis=1)
                  )
```

Output:

```
           teams     area league          new_teams
0  CubsWhite Sox  Chicago    MLB  [Cubs, White Sox]
1        Red Sox   Boston    MLB          [Red Sox]
2       Blue Jay  Toronto    MLB         [Blue Jay]
```